# Rabbitmq , send message to two clients at the same time

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm developing a Java REST API service and now I need to make a TCP connection between server and mobile devices to send message. I have found that RabbitMQ is a good idea but I'm really newbee in AMQP protocol. The question is how to send message from server to two clients that read bytes from the same queue.

My code:

```
public class RabitSecClient {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages2");

        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(" [x] Received 2 '" + message + "'");
            }
        };

        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
    }
}
```

I execute this code twice for testing and when I send message only first client take it. What is the reason?

Comment: Have a look at the FANOUT queue and checkout https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi look into below site may be you got the answer of you question. Basically RabbitMq is based on publish subscribe mechanism if you put any msg to particular queue. Any number of user got that msg if that access same queue.

https://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric52/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.rabbitmq.2.8/rabbit-web-docs/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html